# Ionic FirebasePlugin.verifyPhoneNumber() not working in iOS

Tags: javascript, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-authentication

Ionic 3 Firebase phone authentication doesn't work in iOS, but works fine in Android.

I’m doing phone number verification using Firebase in Ionic 3. The function window.FirebasePlugin.verifyPhoneNumber()
works fine on an Android device, but is totally ignored in iOS. It worked before, but I had to remove & re-add iOS platform (for another reason), and it hasn’t worked since.

Here's what it looks like...

```
declare var window;
//... Some other stuff
window.FirebasePlugin.verifyPhoneNumber(tele, 60, (credential)=> {
        console.log("verified");
}, (error) => {
   console.warn("Error verifying phone number:", JSON.stringify(error));
});
```

In Android, the above code works fine and it prints "verified". In iPhone, nothing prints (completely ignored). Not even the 'error' part.
I've searched for hours, but no luck.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, did you switch on "Background mode" and inside select checkbox "Remote notifications" in Xcode? https://prnt.sc/ojaw2i

Answer (score 0):

Is `window.FirebasePlugin` defined? if you set a breakpoint or console.log it.

And did you try to re-add the plugin after you remove/add the iOS platform ? (`ionic cordova plugin add plugin name`)

Comment: I tried readding the plugin, but no luck. `window.FirebasePlugin` isn't defined, per-se. `window` is though. I followed the example in the plugin's site.

Comment: To confirm that `window.FirebasePlugin` is defined, I ran `window.FirebasePlugin.getToken()` and a token was generated.

Comment: Yes @GChevass, I tried that, and still it didn't work.

Comment: hello @ObiE , Are you able to solve this issue for ios , am getting the same error could please help